# How can I keep two projects synced automatically using Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm writing an internal math library and I want two versions of it, one that works with Any CPU and another that has some extra functions specific only to x64.  I currently have them set up as 2 projects in the same solution.  The first project is where most of the code is written, and the classes are all partial classes.  The second project is x64 only and I would like to extend those partial classes with some extra functions that take advantage of some processor specific functionality.

I don't have any problem setting this up with linked files, but how can I keep these projects in sync such that any file I add to Project 1 is automatically added to Project 2?

Comment: Did you explicitly decide against solving this in a single project using Conditional compilation symbols and Build configurations?

Comment: @Filburt That sounds like a better idea, is it possible to get a conditional compilation symbol for "processor supports SIMD extensions"?

Comment: That would be one of your Build configurations (just like "Debug" or "Release"). See [define](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0feaad6z(v=vs.110).aspx) for details and check out [How to: Create and Edit Configurations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwybya3w(v=vs.110).aspx) for the general concept.